# message_filter.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer method is not able to invoke the callback function

Tags: python-2.7, camera, ros, calibration, lidar

I am using the **Ouster OS1 LIDAR with ROS Melodic.** The ROS package is publishing the LIDAR data and I am able to view it in RViz. I want to calibrate and fuse the LIDAR data with data from a USB camera, so I have implemented the cv_camera ROS package for the camera and created a new package called calib.

However, I am facing an issue where the **message_filter.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer** method is not able to invoke the callback function. The topics I am subscribing to are

- cv_camera/image_raw
- cv_camera/camera_info
- ouster/points

When I try to echo the ouster/points topic, the timestamp is not showing.

How can I synchronize the time between the data streams ?
I have given below the code used.

```
import rospy
import message_filters
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, CameraInfo, PointCloud2

def callback(image_msg, camera_info_msg, lidar_msg):

# Process synchronized data here
image_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/cv_camera/image_raw', Image)
info_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/cv_camera/camera_info', CameraInfo)
lidar_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/ouster/points', PointCloud2)
ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([image_sub, info_sub, lidar_sub], 10, 0.1)
ts.registerCallback(callback)
rospy.init_node('sync_node')
rospy.spin()
```

Comment: I suspect that the syncroniser can only syncronise topics if all of the topicst report timestamped information and the OS1 not doing this seems suspect. Does the callback run if you only subscribe to the camera_info and image_raw topics?

Comment: @Yassie yes. It's working if I run only the camera_info and image_raw topics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncronising topics with an ApproximateTimeSyncroniser, perhaps unsurprisingly, needs timestamp information for each topic it needs to syncronise. If your OS1 isn't providing that information, you'll need to get it some other way or add it yourself (this is the simpler option).

One way is to subscribe to the raw OS1 topic stream, append timestamp information to the message and republish it on a new topic, which you then feed into your syncroniser. Consider also adding the frame ID to the header if Ouster doesn't do that either to avoid frame transform issues down the line.

For example,

```py
import rospy
import message_filters
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, CameraInfo, PointCloud2

lidar_republisher = rospy.Publisher('/ouster/points_with_timestamp', PointCloud2, queue_size=1)

def add_stamp_to_lidar(lidar_msg):
    stamped_msg = lidar_msg
    stamped_msg.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    stamped_msg.header.frame_id = 'base_link'
    lidar_republisher.pub(stamped_msg)

def callback(image_msg, camera_info_msg, stamped_lidar_msg):
    # Do your thing here
    pass

lidar_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/ouster/points', PointCloud2, add_stamp_to_lidar)
# Process synchronized data here
image_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/cv_camera/image_raw', Image)
info_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/cv_camera/camera_info', CameraInfo)
stamped_lidar_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/ouster/points_with_timestamp', PointCloud2)
ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([image_sub, info_sub, stamped_lidar_sub], 10, 0.1)
ts.registerCallback(callback)

rospy.init_node('sync_node')
rospy.spin()
```

One danger here is that, since your hardware is out of sync, you might be syncronising out-of-date data alongside up-to-date data, meaning your camera's might render a newer frame than the LiDAR and show things that the LiDAR hasn't seen yet and vice-versa. The best solution is the get the topic timestamp from the hardware itself so it might be worthwhile to see if you can update your OS1's firmware or drivers

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my issue was that the timestamp wasn't matching between lidar and camera data. So in the sensor.launch file for ouster I set the **timestamp_mode** to **TIME_FROM_ROS_TIME**.